# Meromorphic function on the Riemann Sphere factorises into linear factors?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-curves

I am reading Rick Miranda's *Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces* and this example looks a little weird.

> Let $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ be a nonzero rational function of $z$, considered as a meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere. We may factor $p$ and $q$ completely into linear factors and write $f$ uniquely as $f(z) = c\prod_i(z - \lambda_i)^{e_i}$, where $c$ is a constant. Then $\mathrm{ord}_{z = \lambda_i}(f) = e_i$.

My question is, why are there only linear factors of $p$ in $f(z) = c\prod_i(z - \lambda_i)^{e_i}$? What happens to $q$?

Answer (score 0):

You did not quote the full text. In my edition it reads:

> … where $c$ is a non-zero constant, the $\lambda_i$'s are distinct complex numbers, **and the exponents $e_i$ are integers**.

Does that answer your question?

If not, here is an explanation.
You can write $p(z)=a\prod_j (z-\mu_j)^{m_j}$ where $a$ is a non-zero constant, the $\mu_j$'s are distinct complex numbers, and the exponents $m_j$ are positive integers. Additionally, you can write $\frac{1}{q(z)}=b\prod_k (z-\nu_k)^{n_k}$ where $b$ is a non-zero constant, the $\nu_k$'s are distinct complex numbers, and the exponents $n_k$ are negative integers. Multiplying these two expressions gives the expression you desire.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now. I forgot the power could be negative.